# What change needs to be made to IdIOHandler.hpp to resolve the resulting W8058 Cannot create pre-compiled header 'reason' warning?

Tags: precompiled-headers, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

Using the IDE Embarcadero C++ Builder Tokyo 10.2, when I `build all` my project I get the following message repeated:

`[bcc32 Warning] IdIOHandler.hpp(242): W8058 Cannot create pre-compiled header: initialized data in header`

The specific line within `IdIOHandler.hpp` is:

`System::UnicodeString __fastcall ReadLnSplit(bool &AWasSplit, System::UnicodeString ATerminator = L"\n", int ATimeout = 0xffffffff, int AMaxLineLength = 0xffffffff, Idglobal::_di_IIdTextEncoding AByteEncoding = Idglobal::_di_IIdTextEncoding());`

Looking into this more, it's my understanding that this file is shipped with the IDE. Thus my question is, what is wrong with this file? Is there something I can manually change to resolve with warning? It's my understanding that if I resolve this warning/issue, the project will compile/build faster.

What change needs to be made to IdIOHandler.hpp to resolve the resulting W8058 Cannot create pre-compiled header 'reason' warning?

Comment: Known issue in Berlin and Tokyo, it is not related to Indy specifically as it affects other non-Indy headers, too. See https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=848256 for more details.  Seems to be an issue when not linking with the Dynamic RTL.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I enabled 'link with Dynamic RTL' for the project and there appears to be no resulting change for either scenario of compiling nor building.